# Deleting Many-To-Many entry

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

How can one delete a Many-To-Many entry?
I have the entities `Client` and `Restaurant` and a relationship table and entity between them: `ClientRestaurant` having the following columns: `ClientID`, `RestaurantID`, `DateOfBill`.
A client entity has the navigational property `ClientRestaurants` which is a list of `ClientRestaurant`.
When I delete an entry from a `Client`'s `ClientRestaurants` list:

> myClient.ClientRestaurants.Remove(myClientRestaurants)

and then try to `SaveChanges` I get the following error:

**`Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the deleted state is not allowed.`**

Update: I set the columns in ClientRestaurants table from SQL Server as Nullable. Now if I do:

> myClient.ClientRestaurants.Remove(myClientRestaurants)
>   myRestaurant.ClientRestaurants.Remove(myClientRestaurants)

and then `SaveChanges` it works fine, I mean the entries from relationships are removed, but in DB remains a row with `NULL` values, and since I have an `UNIQUE INDEX` for those two columns, I can only have one row with `NULL` values. There has to be another solution, but it eludes me.
Any help greatly appreciated.
These are the functions that add and remove records to the intermediary table.

```
Private Function addTehnicianToLucrare(L As Lucrare, T As Tehnician) As TehnicianLucrare
    Dim result As TehnicianLucrare = Nothing
    Dim TL As New TehnicianLucrare
    TL.Tehnician = T
    'T.LucrariTehnician.Add(TL)
    TL.Lucrare = L
    'L.TehnicieniLucrare.Add(TL)
    If TL IsNot Nothing Then result = TL
    Return result
End Function
Private Function removeTehnicianFromLucrare(L As Lucrare, T As Tehnician) As TehnicianLucrare
    Dim result As TehnicianLucrare = Nothing
    Dim TL As TehnicianLucrare = Me._ctx.TehnicieniLucrare.Local.Where(Function(p) p.Tehnician Is T And p.Lucrare Is L).SingleOrDefault
    If TL IsNot Nothing Then
        Me._ctx.TehnicieniLucrare.Remove(TL)
        result = TL
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

> Consider Lucrare as Restaurant and Tehnician as Client from the above description.

UPDATE: I have these Subs:

```
Private Sub list_TehnicieniRaport_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles list_TehnicieniRaport.DoubleClick
    Try
        If Me.list_TehnicieniRaport.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            Dim curTeh = TryCast(Me.list_TehnicieniRaport.SelectedItem, TehnicianLucrare)
            If curTeh IsNot Nothing Then
                'setProperty("TehnicieniLucrare", curTeh.Tehnician)
                moveToDataTable(curTeh.Tehnician)
                'ChangeTracker.HasChanges() gives error here
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        logError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub moveToDataTable(ByRef pTehnician As Tehnician)
    Try
        setProperty("TehnicieniLucrare", pTehnician)
        If getProperty("Edit") Then selectEchipa()
        selectCar()
    Catch ex As Exception
        logError(ex)
    End Try
    'ChangeTracker.HasChanges() DOES NOT give error here.
End Sub
```

This way I get the error, and it appears right after the `moveToDataTable()` sub exits. I had step-by-step debugging and calling `_ctx.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` after every step.
If I move the `setProperty("TehnicieniLucrare", curTeh.Tehnician)` to the `list_TehnicieniRaport_DoubleClick(...)` sub, then I don't get the error, and everything works just fine. I don't understand.....

Comment: Why did you set the Ids nullable? You shouldn't do that, because a record doesn't make sense when one or two ids are null.

Comment: Ok, I was just trying different things. When I set the IDs nullable, I also added a new autoincremented ID column to the table. Now I reverted to original table with the two IDs that make the primary key. I still get the error when I try to SaveChanges.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from your question:

```
having the following columns: ClientID, RestaurantID, DateOfBill.
```

I get the feeling this intermediary table is not automatically generated by EF, but rather a separate table that you individually defined. My main reasoning behind this is that you're adding the `DateofBill`, which means you're manually inserting items in the table.

It might act just like an intermediary table, but EF doesn't see it that way.

If you set up a many-to-many via EF (i.e. not managed by you, but autogenerated), there will still be a table, but it will be hidden behind the ORM. Your code snippet applies to this scenario. In this case, you need to remove the relation; and the internal table row will be deleted by EF. *Because the table is part of describing the relation.*

But if your intermediary table is a separate table that you defined yourself, it is an entity; and you need to handle it just like you would handle any other entity.
*The table is a specifically defined table, and it has two relations, to Client and Restaurant.*

Remove the `ClientRestaurant` entity just like you would any other entity:

```
myContext.ClientRestaurantTable.Remove(myEntityToRemove);
```

Don't worry about the relations. They are contained in that ClientRestaurant row (ClientID, RestaurantID), there won't be a referential issue.

The key part to keep in mind here is that there is a difference between the tables EF autogenerates for you, and an intermediary table you set up yourself (in most cases, this is only done when you need additional columns in that table, like your `DateofBill`)

Comment: You are right. The DateOfBill is a column that I added to the relationship table. `myContext.ClientRestaurantTable.Remove(myEntityToRemove)` still throws the same error.